# Add a value every $n

Tags: google-sheets

I don't know what to actually call this so if it's already been asked and answered, feel free to point me to it.

I have a Google Sheet with a column of fixed currency values (A), and a column of dynamic values (B) that I would like to increase by x, every n in column A.  Ideally the result of this exercise would result in something like (using 1 and 300 as x and n respectively):

```
 A  B
100 1
200 1
300 2
400 2
500 2
600 3
700 3
800 3
900 4
```

The part that for some reason I can't get my head around, is that I want to be able to vary the amount (currently 300 in this example) from another cell.  So for example in C1 I would input whatever number I want to be the value that triggers the increase, say 300, or 400, or 600, whatever.  I also want to have another cell, say D1, that is the number to increase by, so it could be "add 2 every 400" or "add 5 every 800", etc.

I've tried numerous methods and so for every one of them ends up increasing early, or late (rounding issues that I can't seem to solve).  How could I accomplish this task?  Ideally this would use only existing formulas within Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
`=ArrayFormula(FLOOR(A:A / $C$1) * D1 + 1)`

**Explanation**

We take the value from the A column then divide it by C1 then `FLOOR()` it to remove the decimal. We then multiply it by D1 (increment value). Adding 1 to nudge and fix the value.

Comment: Hah!  Seems to work.  Thank you so much, a nice simple solution.  I don't entirely understand the approach but I'll try to dig in and get my head around it.  Thanks!

Comment: Whoops, one followup issue.  Now that I'm using my actual heet, the formula works as `=ArrayFormula(FLOOR(D45:D65 / $F$21) * $E$21 + 1)` but, I would like it to work regardless of the length of the range.  Unfortunately this does not work: `=ArrayFormula(FLOOR(D45:D / $F$21) * $E$21 + 1)`.  Can this ArrayFormula be made to extend indefinitely?

Comment: Strike that, looks like it was related to another formula on my sheet, and a recursive calculation.

Comment: Glad I could help @JVC, if it helps you understand, think of it like a linear function but it only adds the values on whole numbers. [desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dgequ1w3sr)

Comment: Thanks for the followup, unfortunately I don't even know what a "linear function" is lol.  I'm an "accomplished amateur" at best with this stuff.  =)

Comment: OK, now that I'm trying to finalize this, I've hit another snag.  I need to limit the maximum number possible from the arrayformula, but it appears that MAX() cannot be easily used with AFs.  I'm finding mentions of using DMAX and re-formatting some of the source data, but this is really not going to work for my situation.  Is there any way to limit the results from this, to no more than a value in another cell?

Comment: I managed to achieve it using a helper column, but I'd much rather not need this if possible.  I'll make due this way if I must however so thanks either way!